# Prevent admin/Jamf Pro from accessing/deleting 2nd partition

Tags: hard-drive, partition, security, privacy, administrator

The company I work for wants to install [Jamf Pro](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-pro/) on my "work" Macbook.

I want to create a 2nd partition on my Macintosh HD (with its own Mac OS version) for personal use.

If Jamf Pro is installed on the 1st partition, will/can it have access to the 2nd partition?

I guess if Jamf Pro is given admin rights, it can do whatever it wants, even delete the 2nd partition from within the 1st one, so my question is can I protect my 2nd partition in some way, *before* Jamf Pro is installed on the 1st one, so that it has no way of deleting/acccessing the 2nd partition ?

Thanks

Comment: you can have 2 or more Admins on a Mac with equal rights.

Comment: As it is a work computer you might not have the legal right to even try to stop company accounts accessing or deleting your personal data. If you want to protect  your data from the company use a different device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having 2 different "OSes" on 2 partitions should allow you to encrypt them indivually.

If you create a new partition, install mac there, and enable Filevault there, it should not be readible from the other boot partition.

I don't think you can stop it from being deleted though. If the software has admin access it can do what it wants with the disk.